# find the Nth number of this sequence. Two set bits

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

> Look at the following sequence:
> 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 17, 18, 20....
>
> All the numbers in the series has exactly 2 bits set in their binary representation. Your task is simple, you have to find the Nth number of this sequence.
>
> 1 <= T <= 105
> 1 <= N <= 1014

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while ( t > 0 ){
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            t--;
             int x =1;
            while ( n > 0 ){
                
               int y = 0;
                while ( y < x ){
                     n--;
                    if ( n == 0 ){
                        System.out.println((1<<x)|(1<<y));
                    }
                   
                    y++;
                    
                }
                
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is giving me a timeout error  can i have an optimized solution of the given range of inputs

Comment: From a contest?

Comment: `public class Solution` reminds me of hackerrank ...

Comment: those constraints can't give timeout for your solution, i am sure the constraints are 1 <= T <= 10^5
1 <= N <= 10^14

Answer (score 2):

## Examine The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences

This is an integer sequence, which means we should be checking [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences<sup>®</sup>](https://oeis.org). It frequently includes fairly optimal algorithms or mathematical expressions to produce elements in a specific integer sequence, so look there when you want an optimized solution.

After [searching for `3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 17, 18, 20`](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C+5%2C+6%2C+9%2C+10%2C+12%2C+17%2C+18%2C+20), we find that this is [OEIS sequence A018900, "Sum of two distinct powers of 2."](https://oeis.org/A018900), which includes several code snippets we should examine to determine which is fastest.

## Fastest algorithm on OEIS page

> Examining those snippets, the most efficient appears to be Smalltalk code by Hieronymus Fischer (`Version 1` in the `PROG` section):
>
> > ```
> > distinctPowersOf: b
> >   "Version 1: Answers the n-th number of the form b^i + b^j, i>j>=0, where n is the receiver.
> >   b > 1 (b = 2, for this sequence).
> >   Usage: n distinctPowersOf: 2
> >   Answer: a(n)"
> >   | n i j |
> >   n := self.
> >   i := (8*n - 1) sqrtTruncated + 1 // 2.
> >   j := n - (i*(i - 1)/2) - 1.
> >   ^(b raisedToInteger: i) + (b raisedToInteger: j)
> > ```
> >
> > <sup>Above code published in [OEIS sequence A018900](https://oeis.org/A018900) on 20 April 2014, authored by [Hieronymus Fischer](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Hieronymus_Fischer), [licensed by The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/wiki/The_OEIS_End-User_License_Agreement) under [the CC BY-NC 3.0 copyright license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/).</sup>

## Appropriate data type

[Signed 64-bit `long`s run out of space to hold the result and can begin to set incorrect bits after n exceeds 1,953](https://ideone.com/vfWpcu). Since n won't exceed 1,014 in practice, `long` results will be fine.

[Signed 32-bit `int`s run out of space after n exceeds 465](https://ideone.com/6oA13o), so they aren't large enough.

## Solution using optimized algorithm

> Here, we translate the Smalltalk algorithm to Java. Since optimized efficiency is your goal, we'll speed things up very slightly by using `<< 3` to multiply a small `int` value by eight and `>>> 1` to perform floored division by two on a positive `int`:
>
> ```java
> import java.util.Scanner;
>
> public class Solution {
>     // Gives the exact floor of the square root of x.
>     // based on Java algorithm by Programmer Olathe
>     // from http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_an_integer_square_root#Java
>     public static final int floorSqrt(final int x) {
>         return (int) Math.sqrt(x);
>     }
>     
>     // Finds the nᵗʰ integer with exactly two bits set.
>     // Cannot properly handle n > 1953.
>     // based on Smalltalk algorithm by Hieronymus Fischer
>     // from https://oeis.org/A018900
>     public static final long nthWithTwoBitsSet(final int n) {
>         // Find the indexes of the two bits.
>         final int i = (floorSqrt((n << 3) - 1) + 1) >>> 1;
>         final int j = n - ((i*(i - 1)) >>> 1) - 1;
>         
>         // Return a long with the two bits set.
>         return (1L << i) | (1L << j);
>     }
>     
>     public static final void main(final String[] args) {
>         final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
>         for (int t = in.nextInt(); t > 0; t--) {
>             System.out.println(nthWithTwoBitsSet(in.nextInt()));
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

## Solution with slightly improved efficiency

> We can gain further efficiency at the cost of bad design by combining all three methods into one:
>
> ```java
> import java.util.Scanner;
>
> public class Solution {
>     // Cannot properly handle n > 1953.
>     // based on Java floored-square-root algorithm by Programmer Olathe
>     // from http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_an_integer_square_root#Java
>     // based on Smalltalk nᵗʰ-with-two-bits-set algorithm by Hieronymus Fischer
>     // from https://oeis.org/A018900
>     public static final void main(final String[] args) {
>         final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
>         for (int t = in.nextInt(); t > 0; t--) {
>             final int n = in.nextInt();
>             
>             // Find the indexes of the two bits.
>             final int i = (((int) Math.sqrt((n << 3) - 1)) + 1) >>> 1;
>             final int j = n - ((i*(i - 1)) >>> 1) - 1;
>             
>             // Print a long with the two bits set.
>             System.out.println((1L << i) | (1L << j));
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Beautiful. I am just wondering whether you are taking the fun away from the asker, who apparently wanted to solve this challenge himself? I’m not saying that it’s easy to write a helpful answer that doesn’t do this.

Comment: The `int` overflow issue is a good point (I hadn’t thought of that, but you are entirely correct).

Comment: @OleV.V. Well, they asked "can i have an optimized solution of the given range of inputs", but I can see your point, so I've spoilered it.

Answer (score 1):

For my explanation I number the bit position from the least significant bit from 0. So 3 has bits 0 and 1 set. 5 has bits 0 and 2 set, etc.

There are 0 numbers where the most significant set bit is bit 0 (because then there is no other bit to set). 1 number where it’s bit 1 (3). Two numbers where it’s bit 2 (101 = 5 and 110 = 6). And so forth. *m* numbers where the most significant set bit is bit *m*.

This in turn means that up to and including numbers where bit *b* is the more significant of the two set bits, there are *b* * (*b* + 1) / 2 numbers. Let’s for a moment assume this is equal to *N*. Then according to the formual for solving a quadratic equation *b* = (sqrt(8 * *N* + 1) - 1) / 2. If this isn’t a whole number, it’s because *N* didn’t exactly equal the formula I said. Round up to find *b* and then find which other bit must be set for everything to agree.

I am on purpose not giving you the full solution. You wanted to solve this problem, you do the work. I hope my input is useful.

The other — smaller but easier — optimization is: Find the largest *N* among the test cases. Calculate the numbers of the sequence up to this largest *N* and put them into an array (you may modify your code from the question to do this). Then print all the required results by looking them up in the array. Language nitpicking: One may may argue that this is not literally an *optimization* since this word comes from latin *optimus* meaning *best* and it doesn’t produce the fastest possible program.